# Как прикрутить JScrollPane к JTextArea?

Tags: jscrollpane, java, swing

Здравствуйте.

Есть такое объявление JTextArea с попыткой прикрутить к нему JScrollPane:

```
    log = new JTextArea(logText);
    log.setBounds(21, 25, 150, 272);
    log.setLineWrap(true);
    log.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(21, 25, 150, 272);
    scrollPane.add(log);
    log.setEditable(false);
    frame.add(log);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
```

Не работает,нету полосы прокрутки,даже когда log заполнен полностью.Пробовал через getContentPane - такой же результат.

Весь код вот тут: http://pastebin.com/F60zB1qw

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Была у меня такая проблема. Решалась не последующей передачей JTextArea через метод add(), а указанием его в конструкторе при создании JScroolPane, то бишь:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);
```

И добавлять на JFrame, если не ошибаюсь, нужно будет только JScrollPane